# Preserve viewcontroller modal after close open app

Tags: ios, swift

Using Reachability to check the Internet connection. I use it to show a modal with a message of an active connection being required to use the app. This is global so it has a listener in the appdelegate. On the modal I have a button to go to settings. Everything at this point works well and the modal appears as required. The problem is that I can't figure out a way to dismiss the modal after the user has enabled internet and returns to the app. The function does get called, just that nothing happens to the modal. This is the bit of code I am using in attempt to dismiss the modal upon returning and it isn't working.

```
var noInternetViewController: NoInternetViewController!

func hideMissingInternetController(){
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: IdentifierNames.ModalsStoryBoard, bundle: nil)
    noInternetViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IdentifierNames.NoInternetViewController) as! NoInternetViewController

    if noInternetViewController.isViewLoaded && noInternetViewController.view.window != nil {
        noInternetViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The function resides in a basecontroller for the entire app.

I can't tell if my process is wrong or something else. Any suggestions/ideas would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE: So the solution was actually fairly simple. Since I have an active listener on Reachability, the function to show the modal will be shown whenever there is not a live connection. The modal has a button to go to settings. So what I do is whenever the settings button is tapped, I close the modal and then upon returning to the app if the connection is still not live, the modal will just be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `NoInternetViewController` with:

```
noInternetViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IdentifierNames.NoInternetViewController) as! NoInternetViewController
```

This is **not** the view controller that instance is currently presented.

You need to pass the presented internet view controller instance to the `noInternetViewController` member of where `hideMissingInternetController` is defined then dismiss it using:

```
noInternetViewController.presentingViewController?.dismiss(...)
```

Comment: You are right. But assigning it to the variable won't work either as the instance disappears upon leaving the app. Need a way to retain the instance or alternative.

Comment: look at my updated answer. If you need the noInternet connection instance just for dismissing then you don't need to.

Comment: Just tried with presentedViewController and it didn't work either.

Comment: yeah I apologize. I got confused myself. If self is the one presenting the no internet VC then you should use self.dismiss...

Comment: No problem. self was not presenting so the presentedViewController was more in line.

Comment: hideMissingInternetController() method where is it declared?